# Determining convergence of a series with an arbitrary index

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I am given this infinite series:

$$\sum_{n=a}^{\infty} \frac{6x^n}{\sqrt[5]{n}}$$

and asked to determine its interval of convergence. I applied the Ratio Test and found that the series converges for values of $-1\leq x < 1$. However, I am a little unsettled by the index of summation. So far, all the problems I have done involved indices such as $n=0$ and $n=1$. The index here starts from an arbitrary number $a$, I assume that's what they mean. Does this change anything regarding my problem? Would it be correct to say that since the Ratio Test involves taking a limit an infinity, it does not matter where we start the summation?

Comment: A finite number of terms don't affect convergence. In fact, $\sum_{n\ge a}c_n = \sum_{n\ge 0}c_n -\sum_{n=0}^{a-1}c_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Providing that the terms $u_0, u_1, \dots, u_{a-1}$ are defined, the radius of convergence of the power series $S(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty u_n x^n$ is the one of the power series $S_a(x)= \sum_{k=a}^\infty u_n x^n$ as we have

$$S_a(x) = S(x) - P_a(x)$$ were $P_a(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{a-1} u_n x^n$ is a polynomial that is defined on all $\mathbb C$. Therefore $S(x)$ converges if and only if $S_a(x)$ converges.